# Configure Tomcat webapps directory as per project's output folder structure

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

My project's output folder structure is `webapps\WEB-INF\classes`. Here War file get all the content inside `webapps` folder. But when I build my project, tomcat only takes content inside under `webapps\WEB-INF\classes` folder. So in Tomcat's webapps folder `<contextRoot>/content of classes folder`. I want to configure to be `<contextRoot>/content under webapps folder`.

IDE is Eclipse Juno 3.6 and tomcat 6.0 server.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a Dynamic Web Project, you can configure those settings in the Deployment Assembly in your project properties. (Right click your project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly.)

Hope this helps.